# Wordpress multisite with modified url structure

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, dns, subdomain

I'm beginning work on a Wordpress multisite using the sub domain structure but it was requested to have the URL structure like this:

- parentsite.domain.com
- childsite.domain.com

As opposed to the default:

- parentsite.domain.com
- childsite.parentsite.domain.com

What would be the best way to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

You can play with rewrite rules as you wish :

```
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array','my_insert_rewrite_rules', 99 );
add_action( 'wp_loaded','my_flush_rules' );

function my_flush_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

function my_insert_rewrite_rules( $rules ) {
    //do whatever you want !
    print_r( $rules );
    return $rules;
}
```

You'll only have to make sure site url is updated in db.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to setup a standard Multisite / Subdomain configuration...

Create 2 sites in Wordpress (using MySites->Network Admin->Sites):

a.domain.com
and
b.domain.com

Then point DNS A records for both subdomains at the IP of your wordpress server.